# Why is my Dafny assertion failing on both x == y and x != y?

Tags: dafny

I'm following the tutorials [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_tx3lk7yn4) and the code seems correct but when I test using assertions I get an error!

Running the program prints the correct answer, but the assertions seem to be paradoxical. When a show the counter examples it seems that `-1` is considered even though it shouldn't be.

```
method binarySearch(a:array<int>, key:int) returns (r:int) 
    requires forall i,j :: 0 <= i <= j < a.Length ==> a[i] <= a[j]
    ensures 0 <= r ==> r < a.Length && a[r] == key 
    ensures r < 0 ==> forall i :: 0 <= i < a.Length ==> a[i] != key
{

    var lo, hi := 0, a.Length;

    while (lo < hi) 
        invariant 0 <= lo <= hi <= a.Length
        invariant forall i :: 0 <= i < lo ==> a[i] < key
        invariant forall i :: hi <= i < a.Length ==> a[i] > key
        decreases hi - lo;
    {
        var mid := (lo + hi) / 2;
        if key < a[mid] 
        {
            hi := mid;
        }
        else if key > a[mid]
        {
            lo := mid + 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            return mid;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}


// tests
method Main() 
{
    var a := new int[6][1,2,3,4,5,6];
    var r := binarySearch(a, 5);

    assert r == 4;  // fails
    assert r != 4;  // also fails
}
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dafny uses post-condition of method to reason about result of method call.

Here post-condition is

- If r is between 0 to array length, element at r is equal to key
- If r is less than 0, it is not in array.

Dafny doesn't know which of these is vacuous, but you can hint it.
Guarding `assert r == 4` with `if r >= 0 && r < a.Length` will make it verify.

Alternatively after adding `assert a[4] == 5` before `assert r == 4`, verification will go through.

Reason for strange error is after call to binary search, these are facts known to dafny

- `assert (r < 0) || (0 <= r < 6)`
- `assert (r < 0) ==> forall i :: 0 <= i < a.Length ==> a[i] != 5`
- `assert (0 <= r < 6) ==> a[r] == 5`

Using these it can neither prove `r == 4` nor `r != 4`. Dafny doesn't seem to propagate information like `assert a[0] == 1` etc by default to prover, you have to explicitly ask for it.

Comment: Interesting. So runtime assertions don't exist in Dafny?

Comment: Dafny programs are verified statically, preconditions, postconditions, assert are removed from runtime.

Comment: Are runtime assertions possible or obsolete?

Comment: `expect` statements (https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/547) can  do runtime assert.